Python py7zr extracting .7z archive differently to Linux command line 7zip
I have created a .7z archive using the usual basic Windows UI. It is my understanding this defaults to relative paths for any archives created. When looking in the archive post creation, all I see is a directory called 'autocfg'. When I experimented with absolute paths this changed (as expected).
When unzipping on a Google Colab Linux machine using the below Python script:
import py7zr

inpath = '/usr/local/lib/python3.10/virtual-environments/autocfg/lib/python3.10/site-packages/autocfg/colorama.7z'
outpath = '/usr/local/lib/python3.10/virtual-environments/autocfg/lib/python3.10/site-packages'

with py7zr.SevenZipFile(inpath, mode='r') as szfile:
   szfile.extractall(path=outpath)
szfile.close()

I get the following output:
site-packages
    - Program Files
        - My Sub Dir
            - My Sub Dir 2
                - autocfg
                    colorama

...this is the directory structure from Windows that has been preserved somehow. When I try using the Linux command line version of 7zip as per the below:
!7za e -y /usr/local/lib/python3.10/virtual-environments/autocfg/lib/python3.10/site-packages/autocfg/colorama.7z -o/usr/local/lib/python3.10/virtual-environments/autocfg/lib/python3.10/site-packages

...the .7z file 'colorama' unpacks correctly to:
site-packages
    - colorama

...why is py7zr exhibiting this behaviour? What can I amend in my code to get my output as per how Linux command line is delivering it?

What does szfile.getnames() return?

@MarkRansom it returns a list with values such as 'Program Files/Python Git Repo/ComfyUI Custom Node Packages/Packages2/autocfg/colorama'. I'm not sure how that has happened when creating the archive. Is there a py7zr option I can use that will give me the same result as the command line version?

I've never used py7zr myself, and the documentation is sparse on options you can use.  Hopefully someone sees the question who can help.
